# Should i learn SOAP API or Rest Assured API Testing?

Tags: api-testing, api, postman, rest-assured, readyapi

I am new to API testing world.

Should i learn Rest Assured API testing using maven and eclipse or should i learn all things on Soap UI or Postman tool?

Which tool is more in demand in IT industry and which has more scope in future.

Comment: Your question would be classified as "Opinion-based". I suggest adding context about your problem in hand and what you trying to solve.

Answer (score 3):

**Don't focus too much on tooling.**

Tools will go out of fashion. Perhaps not this year, not in 2 years, but definitely a few times during your career life (provided you are not at the end of it, but have, say, 5+ year ahead).

Here are some points along which you might want to explore:

- what an API is and what we're trying to achieve with it
- what problems web services solve
- what the architecture behind web services is, what other options there are
- what protocols are involved, how do they work
- what REST actually means, what are the principles here
- ...

If you approach your learning this way, it will be easy to go from one tool to another.

On the other hand, choose tools that are intuitive, have good support, and allow you to be a more powerful Tester.

Comment: @Thanks for the answer. I will start with Rest Assured. Is it go to start with?

Answer (score 0):

Any testing company prefer the candidates those can work on different technologies and platforms in the field of automation, It can be either designing of automation frameworks, working on UI, functional, API or Performance testing.

For API testing multiple tools like REST-assured, SoapUI, Postman and JMeter are available, and we can use them by considering our requirement.

Both Soap API and Rest Assured have their own features, like Soap API is widely used for functional testing and you can use this
if wants to proceed with manual testing and Rest Assured is a Java library for testing RESTful APIs, which can be used in automation frameworks.

As per my experience, Soap library has compatibility issue while integrating other libraries which are mandatory for successful automation framework.

So, by considering the java, Jenkins integration and compatibility for third party tools, You can go for Rest Assured over Soap UI.